# Celery Async Issue in Django's Docker Container

Tags: django, docker, django-rest-framework, rabbitmq, celery

I have deployed micro services on docker containers using celery for queue management. Problem is that when I call sync operation it can access database container but async operation gives us this error `HTTPConnectionPool(host='database', port=83): Max retries exceeded with url:`

Can anybody tell me the root cause of this behavior? why the same API is executing in sync and not in async?

Comment: Can you please add some more details what are you trying to do using async and what was done in sync?

Comment: The sync and async functionalities are same. They both hit API of my database container. Only the async functionality require some more logic which I handle in pre/post run of celery which uses RabbitMQ as a broker.  The only issue is, sync is hitting the database API perfectly but the async giving the connection timeout error which I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Did you check if the docker sql accepts multiple connections or many connection ? also are the host and port same when you are hitting async like sync ?

Comment: My database container means I've a django project which deals with the database. And yes, the domain and port both are same  in sync and async.

Comment: Can you check the number of active connections when you make the request in the database, also the number of max connections if thats exceeding that should be the case.